# Song identification help, Big band tune

Tags: identify-this-song, jazz

Had this stuck in me head for a couple of days now and it's really bothering me.
Can you help identify it?
I seem to remeber it starts with a bari or trombone maybe with a snare rim click in the background.

I've written out how I think it goes.
[image]

Comment: Need to tie the quavers and semibreves across the bars!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of my big bands has just found the charts for this - and it's a great number! Birdland.

Comment: I found the version that was in my mind now: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2OREWuaLmY Thomas Gansch - Birdland

Answer (score 2):

That's "Birdland" by Weather Report